# Displaying and Saving only true statements

Tags: java, boolean

As part of the program that I am writing I need it to:

1. Compare two strings from two different files
2. Return only the true values, that is the strings that match in the files.
3. Return the number of true values and what lines in the file they are located on.

The code that I have for the comparison at the moment is:

```
    boolean result = mainEmail.trim().contentEquals(deletionemailAddress.trim());
    System.out.println(mainEmail);
    System.out.println(deletionemailAddress);
    System.out.println(result);
```

It uses both trim() and contentEquals() to make sure that the two strings are the same. It then prints out a list of the strings and states whether they are the same or not. What I would like to do is to have none of the false results printed only the true statements (The mainEmail, deletionemailAddress, and result variables) to be printed. I want to count the number of true statements only and return the number of true statements as well as what lines in the mainEmail file they are located on.

What would be the most effective way in order to display only the true statements(matching emails too) and a count saying how many true statements that they are?

Comment: I don't see any "line" number is the above code so we can't help you there. WRT only printing the lines that match, gee seems like a `if (result)` would work well. Also, `int`s work well for counters.

Comment: shows lack of any effort

Comment: Line number doesn't mean line number in the code but in the actual file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard about `if`?

```
boolean result = mainEmail.trim().contentEquals(deletionemailAddress.trim());
int count = 0;
if (result){
    count++;
    System.out.println(mainEmail);
    System.out.println(deletionemailAddress);
    System.out.println(result);
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Have you heard about `while`? ;)

Comment: Only missing this part `what lines in the mainEmail file they are located on` but you answer is identical to what I was thinking, but beat me to posting it.

Comment: Improvement: `if (result == true)` -->`if (result)`.

Comment: @Churk it's really hard to tell without the knowledge about reading these strings form file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had something similar to this but my order was wrong and could not figure out the error. Also I noticed when I tried it that if the System.out.println(count) is located in the if statement then there will be no zeroes to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
// define it somewhere outside of the loop
int counter = 0;

boolean result = mainEmail.trim().contentEquals(deletionemailAddress.trim());

if(result) {
    System.out.println(mainEmail);
    System.out.println(deletionemailAddress);
    System.out.println(result);
    counter++;
}

//at the end
System.out.println("There were " + counter + " true results.");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean result = true;
int count = 0;
while (result){
    original = mainEmail.trim();
    mainEmail = mainEmail.trim().replaceFirst(deletionemailAddress.trim());
    result = original.equals(mainEmail);
    count++;
    System.out.println(mainEmail);
    System.out.println(deletionemailAddress);
    System.out.println(result);
}
System.out.println(count);
```